# Проблемы с установкой Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

Пытался поставить  Vue CLI через `npm install -g @vue/cli`.Началось всё с того,что появилась куча WARN,но вроде был вид того,что установка успешно прошла.Я решил проверить,всё ли хоршошо и ввел `vue --version`,после чего получил:`bash: vue: command not found"`.Кто знает,как можно исправить?
(коды WARN прилагаются)

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
```

Comment: варны здесь не причем, а ответ на ваш вопрос содержится [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957748/8628377) . Попробуйте еще команду `npx @vue/cli create app`

Comment: Данная команда помогла отчасти,но решение нашлось в переустановке VS Code  и Node.js.

Comment: Не уверен конечно что решение от части могло быть в переустановке VSC, он никоем образом не относится к созданию проекта.